# $C^*$ algebra vs Hilbert space

Tags: linear-algebra, hilbert-spaces

I am interested in the application of $C^*$ to quantum mechanics.

A core axiom of the Hilbert space formalism, is that there exists an inner product for all unit vectors:

$$
\langle u,v \rangle
$$

Whereas in $C^*$ algebra, there is a norm

$$
||v||^2=||v^*v||
$$

But the norm applies only to a single element, whereas the inner product applies to two elements. Do we lose anything important for physics by not having an inner product? Or do we use the norm to recover the inner product if needed? Or is it that in QM on Hilbert space we use the inner product of u with itself, and do not need the extra freedom of using two distinct vectors?

Comment: A characterization of norms coming from inner products is the [parallelogram law](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parallelogram_law#The_parallelogram_law_in_inner_product_spaces). Not all norms satisfy it. When they do, you recover the inner product from the norm using the [polarization identity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polarization_identity).

Comment: @plop Is that what people use for QM using C^* algebras?

Comment: My comment is about what you lose for having a norm that doesn't come from an inner product, mathematically. I don't know what this implies for physics.

Comment: In the Hilbert space case, you are taking the scalar product of two state vectors, whereas elements of the $C^*$-algebra are thought of as operators.